# pseudo diagonalize adjacency matrix

Tags: algorithm, matrix, adjacency-matrix

Given an [adjanceny matrix](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Adjacency_matrix) that is rather sparse, meaning there are a lot of zero entries, I would like to do the following: I would like to change the order of the rows and columns of the matrix such that the matrix has the non-zero entries as close as possible to the diagonal line. Then I would get some kind of pseudo diagonal matrix.

I would like to whether there are known algorithm for doing exactly that. After having this pseudo diagonal matrix I that ideally think must be a metric for "how diagonal" we could get.

The reason for doing so is that afterwards I would be able to store the matrix in a much small data-structure which would be faster to store and load.

My own research has shown me that I might not know the correct terminology for the problem so I would be happy to learn about the correct wording of the given problem. And of course get to know algorithms that can do the "pseudo diagonalisation" by changing the order of rows and columns in a matrix.

Comment: Did I miss something really obvious?

Comment: Something like the Cuthill–McKee algorithm, does that fit your requirements?

Comment: Yes. So I want a _band-matrix_ and  _bandwith_ is the metric I am looking for. _Bandwith-Reduction_ is the proper name of the problem. I also found the GPS (Gibbs, Poole and Stockmeyer) algorithm as I have the right terminology now. Thanks @harold for giving the solution. You might want to actually write an answer so I can mark it (and upvote).